# Swift 3: Do I need to link the viewDidAppear function in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, swift3, viewdidappear

I am a beginner in Swift. I am trying to make a basic login and account creation system in a single-view Swift 3 project.

In my ViewController.swift, I have a viewDidAppear function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)
}
```

Here is my main storyboard:
[Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anGJx.png)

Upon opening the app, I want the "protected data" page to open first, then check if user has logged in. If not, the login page should appear. However, I don't know how to achieve this. I tried to link navigation controller, but I don't see the function as an option.

Right now, when I run the simulator, only the "protected data" page shows.

What do I do? In addition, is there anything wrong with my viewDidAppear function?

Answer (score 11):

If you really want this navigation flow

> Upon opening the app, I want the "protected data" page to open first, then check if user has logged in.

then you should organise your `ViewController.swift` like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if /* userDidLogin... REPLACE WITH YOUR CODE*/ {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowLogin", sender: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Of course you also need to:

1. open Storyboard
2. select the segue that connect ViewController to the login view controller
3. assign to it the name `ShowLogin`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Inherit From Target" is checked.

[image]